# Why is my implementation always calling the same derived class?

Tags: c#, oop, dependency-injection, abstract-class, derived-class

I have a base class that accepts a Type as a constructor argument, and two derived classes that inherit from that base class. I also have an interface of that base class, that I inject to use in other places.

When I call the base method "FormatValue", passing different types as parameters, I always get the same result (it call the method in one of the classes, ignoring my type parameter).

What am I doing wrong?

```
public interface IFormatService
{
    string FormatValue(object value);
}
public abstract class FormatService : IFormatService
{
    protected FormatService(Type type)
    { }

    public abstract string FormatValue(object value);
}

public static class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton<IFormatService, CurrencyFormat>()
            .AddSingleton<IFormatService, DateTimeFormat>()
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        var formatService = serviceProvider.GetService<IFormatService>();

        Console.WriteLine(formatService.FormatValue(DateTime.Now));
        Console.WriteLine(formatService.FormatValue(200));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class CurrencyFormat : FormatService
{
    public CurrencyFormat() : base(typeof(decimal))
    {
    }

    public override string FormatValue(object value) => "CurrencyFormatter";
}

public class DateTimeFormat : FormatService
{
    public DateTimeFormat() : base(typeof(DateTime))
    {
    }

    public override string FormatValue(object value) => "DateTimeFormatter";
}
```

Current result:

```
DateTimeFormatter
DateTimeFormatter
```

Expected result:

```
DateTimeFormatter
CurrencyFormatter
```

Comment: Your second registration `.AddSingleton<IFormatService, DateTimeFormat>()` overrides the previous one, you should make `IFormatService` generic `IFormatService<T>` to work properly.

Comment: Thanks! But how do I register a generic interface? As transient? And how can I get the service, since I declare each one for every type I have?

Comment: Your can register as singleton like this `.AddSingleton<IFormatService<DateTime>, DateTimeFormat>()`.

Comment: But then I would have to declare a service for each one of the types I have? Like `var datetimeFormatService = serviceProvider.GetService<IFormatService<DateTime>>();
            var currencyFormatService = serviceProvider.GetService<IFormatService<decimal>>();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call different methods depending on the type of parameter, there are many ways to do it.

One way is by using the `dynamic` that choose the best overload at runtime:

```
public interface IFormatService
{
    string FormatValue(object value);
}

public class FormatService : IFormatService
{
    public string FormatValue(object value)
    {
        dynamic valueAsDynamic = value;

        return FormatValueDynamic(valueAsDynamic);
    }

    string FormatValueDynamic(dynamic value) => FormatValuePrivate(value);

    string FormatValuePrivate(DateTime value) => "DateTimeFormatter";

    string FormatValuePrivate(decimal value) => "CurrencyFormatter";

    string FormatValuePrivate(object value) => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

This way you can add all the methods you need.

Answer (score 1):

Code pointed below overrides your previous CurrencyFormat registration, so it always resolves to DateTimeFormat.

```
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddSingleton<IFormatService, CurrencyFormat>()
    .AddSingleton<IFormatService, DateTimeFormat>() <---------
    .BuildServiceProvider();
```

Comment: Consider adding info from Alessandro's comment in the question, it addresses how to solve it

Comment: @bradbury9 While that's true, I don't think that "solution" will lead OP anywhere. You would have to resolve for each type that shall be formatted. Not really what I would call convenient.